How to crop images within the drawn boundary by cv2?
I want to crop the images which were defined by the boundary lines drawn by cv2.The current script can accurately detect and draw the boundaries on the picture, but I found it's hard to crop the pictures areas defined in the boundary lines. The following script will select the top 2 largest contours. Can anyone help me to edit so that after selecting the top 2 largest contours, it will crop the images within the controus?
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


image_path = r'C:\Users\bear\Good\230903134657_HNN3TDMXY_1_Delam Analysis.jpg' 

image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)


def count_contours(image,th):
    _, binary_image = cv2.threshold(image, th, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    contour_areas = [(cv2.contourArea(contour), contour) for contour in contours]
    contour_areas.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)  # Sort by area, largest first

    total_contours_count = len(contour_areas)
    print(total_contours_count)

    return total_contours_count



def draw_contours(image,th):
    _, binary_image = cv2.threshold(image, th, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)


    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


    contour_areas = [(cv2.contourArea(contour), contour) for contour in contours]
    contour_areas.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)  # Sort by area, largest first

    total_contours_count = len(contour_areas)


    top_contours = [contour for _, contour in contour_areas[:2]]

    contour_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)  
    cv2.drawContours(contour_image, top_contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2) 


    cv2.imwrite('drawcountourtest.png', contour_image)
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(contour_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()


test_count = count_contours(image,130)

if test_count > 300:
    print(test_count)

    draw_contours(image,200)
else:
    print(test_count)
    draw_contours(image,130)  


Where is an image?

You can crop image by contours. To do this you need to extract bounding rectangls or masks of contours and after crop the regions with these boundaries. Here is how it could looks like:
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image_path = r'C:\Users\bear\Good\230903134657_HNN3TDMXY_1_Delam Analysis.jpg' 
image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

def count_contours(image, th):
    _, binary_image = cv2.threshold(image, th, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary_image,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contour_areas = [(cv2.contourArea(contour),contour) for contour in contours]
    contour_areas.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)  # Sort by area, largest first
    return len(contour_areas)

def draw_and_crop_contours(image, th):
    _, binary_image = cv2.threshold(image, th, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary_image,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    
    contour_areas = [(cv2.contourArea(contour),contour) for contour in contours]
    contour_areas.sort(key=lambda x: x[0],reverse=True)
    top_contours = [contour for _, contour in contour_areas[:2]]
    
    contour_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    cv2.drawContours(contour_image, top_contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cropped_images = []
    for i, contour in enumerate(top_contours):
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        
        cropped = image[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        cropped_images.append(cropped)
        
        cropped_filename = f'cropped_image_{i+1}.png'
        cv2.imwrite(cropped_filename, cropped)
        plt.imshow(cropped,cmap='gray')
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.show()

    cv2.imwrite('drawcontourtest.png',contour_image)
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(contour_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()

test_count = count_contours(image, 130)
if test_count > 300:
    draw_and_crop_contours(image, 200)
else:
    draw_and_crop_contours(image, 130)

